# Is there a way to create persistent bullets in Power Point?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, formatting, xml, template

I have added thee custom bullets to the Style Master Text placeholder, however I would like to have a choice to choose one of those three bullets on the fly. These come through a custom font.

This will be a template sent out across 50 employees and I don't want them to have to go the extra steps in selecting a custom bullet each time, depending on which they prefer to use.

Is there a way to make them default or persistent so that its a quick select from the bullets menu?

I am open to "hacking" the XML.

[image]

Comment: Hi.  PowerPoint isn't technically graphic design software.  Might be better to ask this on SuperUser.

Comment: @BillyKerr I disagree, it is a graphic design tool, a crap one albeit, but the question is related to typography /layout/style which is part of graphic design.